# share an angularjs project with TFS 2013

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2013

I new in TFS using,and I wonder please if there's in any way to open an angularJs  project and share it with Team members in TFS 2013

thanks a lot for help :)

Comment: visual studio online ?

Comment: I have created a visual studio account and I have added members to the project but I still can't share my angularjs project :(

Comment: Have you added team members?

Comment: yes gerdi I have added them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several steps you need to follow:

1. Create one [workspace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181383.aspx) in your local machine to map to TFS server path.
2. Put your angularJs project into the workspace folder.
3. Download and install [TFS2013 Power Tool](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f).
4. In the workspace folder, right click the angularJs project you would like to share with other team members and select Team Foundation Server -> Check in.
   [image]

Now, you already checked in the angularJs project, other team members who have required permissions are able to Get and work with it.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/what-is-visual-studio-online-vs.aspx

has integrated project management for all type of projects

Comment: thanks gerdi for the link but how I can open an angularjs project from my desktop and share it with other members that I have allow them access to this project